# Append before line contains a string

Tags: regex, bash, sed, append

I want to append a string before all instances of a partial matching string using sed.

In other words something like

```
LINE ONE OF FILE
LINE TWO OF FILE
```

I want to append NEWLINE before every line that contains LINE

so it will look like this

```
NEWLINE
LINE ONE OF FILE
NEWLINE
LINE TWO OF FILE
```

I have:

```
sed 's/.*$string1.*/$string2\n&/' $file_name
```

i'd like to place `$string2` above every line that contains `$string1` in `$file_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ string1=LINE
$ string2=NEWLINE
$ sed "s/.*$string1/$string2\n&/" file
NEWLINE
LINE ONE OF FILE
NEWLINE
LINE TWO OF FILE
```

You must be careful to inspect `string1` and `string2` to be sure that they do not unintentionally contain any unescaped sed-active characters.

#### Handling `/`

If the strings contain `/`, we need to change the form of the substitution command.  For example:

```
$ string1=LINE
$ string2=NEW/LINE
$ sed "s|.*$string1|$string2\n&|" file
NEW/LINE
LINE ONE OF FILE
NEW/LINE
LINE TWO OF FILE
```

Comment: They do really have directory paths, like /some/directory. How can this be overcome?

Comment: @bbedward That is easily done.  See updated answer for handling `/` characters.

Answer (score 1):

sed has more comands than just `s///`

```
sed '/LINE/ i NEWLINE'
```

For any line matching LINE, `i`nsert the new text.